# How to update List View Model in Asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Hi I am facing issue in update records in MVC. I have created one list view model and in that i want to update some of the records but i am getting error. Please help me.

Here is my code:

```
public async Task<bool> AddPurchase(PurchaseOrderViewModel objModel, List<TableViewModel> tableListDto)
    {
        using (var txn = context.Database.BeginTransaction())
        {
            bool success = true;
            try
            {
                PurchaseOrder purchase1 = new PurchaseOrder();
                purchase1.LoginID = objModel.LoginID;
                purchase1.SupplierID = objModel.SupplierID;
                purchase1.SupplierName = objModel.SupplierName;
                purchase1.LocationID = objModel.LocationID;
                purchase1.Notes = objModel.Notes;
                purchase1.Currency = objModel.Currency;
                purchase1.TotalQuantity = objModel.TotalQuantity;
                purchase1.TotalAmount = objModel.TotalAmount;
                purchase1.TotalVolume = objModel.TotalVolume;
                purchase1.TotalWeight = objModel.TotalWeight;
                purchase1.TotalLandedCost = Convert.ToDecimal(objModel.TotalCost);
                purchase1.TotalOtherCost = objModel.TotalOtherCost;
                purchase1.Date_Of_Purchase = objModel.Date_Of_Purchase;
                purchase1.Due_Date = objModel.Due_Date;
                purchase1.Date_Arrived = objModel.Date_Arrived;
                purchase1.Date_Departed = objModel.Date_Departed;
                purchase1.CreatedBy = objModel.LoginID;
                purchase1.CreatedOn = objModel.CreatedOn;
                purchase1.UpdatedBy = objModel.LoginID;
                purchase1.UpdatedOn = objModel.UpdatedOn;
                purchase1.Status = StatusConstant.Active;
                context.PurchaseOrders.Add(purchase1);
                await context.SaveChangesAsync();
                success = true;

                int latest = purchase1.PurchaseID;

                PO_Landed_Cost cost = new PO_Landed_Cost();
                cost.LoginID = objModel.LoginID;
                cost.PurchaseID = latest;
                cost.Packaging_Costs = objModel.Packaging_Cost;
                cost.Packaging_Costs_Date_Paid = objModel.Packaging_Costs_Date_Paid;
                cost.Inspection_Costs = objModel.Inspection_Cost;
                cost.Inspection_Costs_Date_Paid = objModel.Inspection_Costs_Date_Paid;
                cost.Freight_And_Duty_Tax = objModel.Freight_Cost;
                cost.Freight_And_Duty_Tax_Date_Paid = objModel.Freight_And_Duty_Tax_Date_Paid;
                cost.Other_Costs = objModel.Other_Cost;
                cost.Total_Landed_Cost = objModel.TotalOtherCost;
                context.PO_Landed_Costs.Add(cost);
                context.SaveChanges();

                OrderDetail order = new OrderDetail();
                PO_Landed_Cost_Spread spread1 = new PO_Landed_Cost_Spread();
                List<DataDisplayViewModel> data = new List<DataDisplayViewModel>();

                if (tableListDto != null)
                {
                    foreach (var item in tableListDto)
                    {
                        //First we take all the basic things

                        var a = Convert.ToDecimal(item.Qty);    //Quantity
                        var b = Convert.ToDecimal(purchase1.TotalQuantity); //Total Quantity
                        var e = Convert.ToDecimal(objModel.TotalOtherCost); //TotalOtherCost
                        var g = Convert.ToDecimal(item.Price);  //Price
                        var j = Convert.ToDecimal(item.Volume);  //Volume
                        var l = Convert.ToDecimal(item.Weight);  //Weight
                        var c = Math.Round(Convert.ToDecimal((a / b) * 100), 2); //Total Percent(Quantity)
                        var f = Math.Round(Convert.ToDecimal(((c * e) / a) / 100), 2); // Quantity Unit Price(Indirect Cost)
                        var h = Math.Round(Convert.ToDecimal(f + g), 2);  //Landed Cost Unit Price (Quantity)
                        var i = Math.Round(Convert.ToDecimal(h * a), 2);  //New Total (Quantity)
                        var k = Math.Round(Convert.ToDecimal(a * j), 2); //Total Volume
                        var m = Math.Round(Convert.ToDecimal(a * l), 2); //Total Weight

                        DataDisplayViewModel datalist = new DataDisplayViewModel();
                        datalist.LoginID = objModel.LoginID;
                        datalist.PurchaseID = latest;
                        datalist.Stock_ID = item.Pid;
                        datalist.Stock_Name = item.ProductName;
                        datalist.Quantity = Convert.ToInt32(item.Qty);
                        datalist.Price = Convert.ToDecimal(item.Price);
                        datalist.Amount = Convert.ToDecimal(item.Amount);

                        datalist.Volume = Convert.ToInt32(item.Volume);
                        datalist.Total_Volume = Convert.ToInt32(k);
                        datalist.Weight = Convert.ToInt32(item.Weight);
                        datalist.Total_Weight = Convert.ToInt32(m);
                        datalist.Total_Percent = Convert.ToString(c);
                        datalist.Indirect_Cost_UnitPrice = Convert.ToString(f);
                        datalist.Landed_Cost_UnitPrice = Convert.ToString(h);
                        datalist.New_Amount = i;
                        data.Add(datalist);
}

                    var totalweight = data.Where(x => x.PurchaseID == latest).Select(x => x.Total_Weight).Sum();
                    var totalvolume = data.Where(x => x.PurchaseID == latest).Select(x => x.Total_Volume).Sum();

                    foreach (var item in tableListDto)
                    {
                        var z = Convert.ToInt32(item.Price);
                        var a = Convert.ToInt32(item.Qty);  //Qty
                        var l = Convert.ToDecimal(item.Weight);  //Weight
                        var j = Convert.ToDecimal(item.Volume);  //Volume
                        var d = Math.Round(Convert.ToDecimal(((a * l) / totalweight) * 100), 2); //Total Percent Of Weight
                        var e = Convert.ToInt32(objModel.TotalOtherCost); //Total Other Cost
                        var f = Math.Round(Convert.ToDecimal(((d * e) / a) / 100), 2);

                        var h = Convert.ToDecimal(a + f);  // Landed Cost Unit Price Of Weight
                        var i = Convert.ToString(h * a);  // New Total Of Weight
                        var m = (a * j / totalvolume) * 100;  //Total Percent Of Volume
                        var o = Math.Round(Convert.ToDecimal(((m * e) / a) / 100), 2);  //Unit Price Of Volume
                        var q = Math.Round(Convert.ToDecimal(z + o), 2); // Landed Cost Unit Price Of Volume
                        var r = Convert.ToInt32(q * a); //New Total Of Volume

                        data.Where(x => x.PurchaseID == latest).FirstOrDefault();
                        data.Where(x => x.PurchaseID == latest).FirstOrDefault().Indirect_Cost_WeightUnitPrice = Convert.ToString(f);
                        data.Where(x => x.PurchaseID == latest).FirstOrDefault().Landed_Cost_WeightUnitPrice = Convert.ToString(h);
                        data.Where(x => x.PurchaseID == latest).FirstOrDefault().New_WeightAmount = Convert.ToDecimal(i);
                        data.Where(x => x.PurchaseID == latest).FirstOrDefault().Total_Percent_Volume = Convert.ToString(m);
                        data.Where(x => x.PurchaseID == latest).FirstOrDefault().Indirect_Cost_VolumeUnitPrice = Convert.ToString(o);
                        data.Where(x => x.PurchaseID == latest).FirstOrDefault().Landed_Cost_VolumeUnitPrice = Convert.ToString(q);
                        data.Where(x => x.PurchaseID == latest).FirstOrDefault().New_VolumeAmount = Convert.ToDecimal(r);
                        context.Entry(data).State = EntityState.Added;
                        context.SaveChanges();
}

                    foreach (var item in data)
                    {
                        order.LoginID = objModel.LoginID;
                        order.PurchaseID = item.PurchaseID;
                        order.Stock_ID = item.Stock_ID;
                        order.Quantity = item.Quantity;
                        order.Price = item.Price;
                        order.Amount = item.Amount;
                        order.CreatedBy = objModel.LoginID;
                        order.CreatedOn = objModel.CreatedOn;
                        order.UpdatedBy = objModel.LoginID;
                        order.UpdatedOn = objModel.UpdatedOn;
                        order.Status = StatusConstant.Active;
                        order.Stock_Name = item.Stock_Name;
                        order.Volume = item.Volume;
                        order.Total_Volume = item.Total_Volume;
                        order.Weight = item.Weight;
                        order.Total_Weight = item.Total_Weight;
                        context.OrderDetails.Add(order);
                        context.SaveChanges();


                        spread1.PurchaseID = item.PurchaseID;
                        spread1.OrderID = order.OrderID;
                        spread1.LoginID = item.LoginID;
                        spread1.Total_Percent = item.Total_Percent;
                        spread1.Indirect_Cost_UnitPrice = item.Indirect_Cost_UnitPrice;
                        spread1.Landed_Cost_UnitPrice = item.Landed_Cost_UnitPrice;
                        spread1.New_Amount = item.New_Amount;
                        spread1.Total_Percent_Volume = item.Total_Percent_Volume;
                        spread1.Indirect_Cost_VolumeUnitPrice = item.Indirect_Cost_VolumeUnitPrice;
                        spread1.Landed_Cost_VolumeUnitPrice = item.Landed_Cost_VolumeUnitPrice;
                        spread1.New_VolumeAmount = item.New_VolumeAmount;
                        spread1.Total_Percent_Weight = item.Total_Percent_Weight;
                        spread1.Indirect_Cost_WeightUnitPrice = item.Indirect_Cost_WeightUnitPrice;
                        spread1.Landed_Cost_WeightUnitPrice = item.Landed_Cost_WeightUnitPrice;
                        spread1.New_WeightAmount = item.New_WeightAmount;
                        context.PO_Landed_Cost_Spreads.Add(spread1);
                        context.SaveChanges();
                    }

                }
                else
                {
                    order.LoginID = objModel.LoginID;
                    order.PurchaseID = latest;
                    order.CreatedBy = objModel.LoginID;
                    order.CreatedOn = objModel.CreatedOn;
                    order.UpdatedBy = objModel.LoginID;
                    order.UpdatedOn = objModel.UpdatedOn;
                    order.Status = StatusConstant.Active;
                    context.OrderDetails.Add(order);
                    context.SaveChanges();

                    PO_Landed_Cost_Spread spread = new PO_Landed_Cost_Spread();
                    spread.LoginID = objModel.LoginID;
                    spread.PurchaseID = latest;
                    spread.OrderID = order.OrderID;
                    context.PO_Landed_Cost_Spreads.Add(spread);
                    context.SaveChanges();

                }

                txn.Commit();

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                txn.Dispose();
                success = false;
            }
            return success;
        };
    }
```

In this code i want to update records when first i need to find some values and then i need to update in the list view model and then i need to update in the table. But i am unable to do that. Please help me in this.

Comment: Plz help me i m stuck here.

Comment: should show the errors and show the message in the Exception .